# Encrypting with Asymmetric keys

Tags: public-key, hybrid-encryption

I'm designing a system where the client asked for documents to be encrypted with "asymmetric cryptography".

I've explained them that the best practice is to encrypt the data with a symmetric algorithm using a randomly generating key and then, using an asymmetric algorithm, to encode that key. The entire scheme is "asymmetric" but it uses multiple algorithms. I offered the usual performance/convenience arguments.

However they are insisting that we should only use asymmetric algorithms because they "have read that is better".

I'm preparing a note for them to better explain the topic and I would greatly benefit of official documents. I browsed the NIST, FIPS, RFC documents and so on but they are too wide to be used as a reference for a customer that is not well versed on this topic.

Does anyone have some pointers to authoritative sources that explain the best practices and that I could use to back up my arguments?

Answer (score 1):

The PGP, which is well known, uses what is in your mind, hybrid solution. [Here](https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/vpns/pgp-hybrid-solution-717) a short documentation for your cause.

Comment: Thanks, I'll surely use it as it gives a very clear explanation. Even if SANS is well known, I was hoping for something even more "official".

Answer (score 0):

You're indeed looking for hybrid encryption. Shoup has a lot of papers on hybrid encryption and proposals for KEM/DEM approaches, for example [this](http://shoup.net/papers/iso-2_1.pdf) submission. It describes the motivation and security for such a framework.

Comment: Thanks. I'll make use of that as well. in the meantime I've found a NIST document: http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a389360.pdf that provides guidelines on this aspect. Of course, the more I can add, the better.